# SQL Server Select INTO with constant column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to Select all of the columns from one table to another. However, the table I am selecting into has an extra column that holds a datetime value. Is there a way to

```
SELECT *, GETDATE() FROM old_table INTO new_table
```

Comment: Simply add a matching column alias name `GETDATE() AS [your target column name here]`

Comment: ... or, if you don't need the exact timestamp of your `INSERT`, simply leave it empty and `UPDATE` your datetime column afterwards.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect for SQL Server. In addition, you cannot use the <select ... into ...> form to insert rows into an existing table. That form will always create a table and it will generate a runtime error if the table already exists. To insert rows into an existing table, you use an insert statement. And yes, you can add expressions or constants to your SELECT query to populate columns that are not populated directly from the source table.

Answer (score 1):

As @SMor pointed out the query syntax is incorrect as per SQL Server. Also, you can't `SELECT INTO` an existing table. It has to be a new table.

The correct syntax would be:

```sql
SELECT *, GETDATE() INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

However, this is also incorrect and will throw the following error when executed.

`An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.`

The correct way to use `SELECT INTO` statement is to list all the column names explicitly for creating the destination table:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, GETDATE() as col3 INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

However, if you already have the destination table defined then you can use `INSERT` statement

```sql
INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, GETDATE() as col3 FROM old_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, GETDATE() as DateCol
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;
```

Something like this should do it.